# Moved a Laravel project from one computer to another and getting a route error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I moved a laravel project from one computer to another and i'm getting rout error's. One thing that's strange is the url's on the previous computer had http://localhost:8000/public/order/create but on the new computer its http://localhost:8000/order/create

If i add the public manually it still doesnt work. Any ideas?

Error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 823
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in     CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/Users/mccray/Desktop/owe/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Route File:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' =>[ 'web']], function () {
  Route::any('user/login', ['as' => 'user.login', 'uses' => 'UserController@login']);
Route::any('user/dologin', ['as' => 'user.dologin', 'uses' => 'UserController@dologin']);});

Route::group(['middleware' =>[ 'web','auth']], function () {
Route::any('/', function () { return view('user.dashboard'); });
Route::any('user/dashboard', ['as' => 'user.dashboard', 'uses' => 'UserController@dashboard']);
Route::any('user/logout', ['as' => 'user.logout' , 'uses' => 'UserController@logout']);

Route::any('sos/create', ['as' => 'sos.create', 'uses' => 'SosController@create']);
Route::any('sos/index', ['as' => 'sos.index' , 'uses' => 'SosController@index']);
Route::any('sos/store', ['as' => 'sos.store' , 'uses' => 'SosController@store']);
Route::any('sos/show/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.show' , 'uses' => 'SosController@show']);
Route::any('sos/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.edit' , 'uses' => 'SosController@edit']);
Route::any('sos/update/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.update' , 'uses' => 'SosController@update']);
Route::any('sos/destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.destroy' , 'uses' => 'SosController@destroy']);
Route::any('sos/submit/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.submit' , 'uses' => 'SosController@submit']);
Route::any('sos/approve/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.approve' , 'uses' => 'SosController@approve']);
Route::any('sos/reject/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.reject' , 'uses' => 'SosController@reject']);
Route::any('sos/customer-search', ['as'=>'sos.customer-search','uses'=>'SosController@search']);
Route::any('sos/customer-selected', ['as'=>'sos.customer-selected','uses'=>'SosController@customerSelected']);

Route::any('order/create', ['as' => 'order.create', 'uses' => 'OrderController@create']);
Route::any('order/index', ['as' => 'order.index' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@index']);
Route::any('order/store', ['as' => 'order.store' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@store']);
Route::any('order/show/{id}', ['as' => 'order.show' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@show']);
Route::any('order/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'order.edit' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@edit']);
Route::any('order/update/{id}', ['as' => 'order.update' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@update']);
Route::any('order/destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'order.destroy' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@destroy']);
Route::any('order/submit/{id}', ['as' => 'order.submit' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@submit']);
Route::any('order/approve/{id}', ['as' => 'order.approve' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@approve']);
Route::any('order/reject/{id}', ['as' => 'order.reject' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@reject']);
Route::any('order/customer-search', ['as'=>'order.customer-search','uses'=>'OrderController@search']);
Route::any('order/customer-selected', ['as'=>'order.customer-selected','uses'=>'OrderController@customerSelected']);
Route::any('order/ship_to_address_area', ['as'=>'order.ship_to_address_area','uses'=>'OrderController@ship_to_address_area']);
Route::any('order/dept_name_field', ['as'=>'order.dept_name_field','uses'=>'OrderController@dept_name_field']);

Route::any('equipment/create', ['as' => 'equipment.create', 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@create']);
Route::any('equipment/index', ['as' => 'equipment.index' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@index']);
Route::any('equipment/store', ['as' => 'equipment.store' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@store']);
Route::any('equipment/show/{id}', ['as' => 'equipment.show' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@show']);
Route::any('equipment/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'equipment.edit' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@edit']);
Route::any('equipment/update/{id}', ['as' => 'equipment.update' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@update']);
Route::any('equipment/destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'equipment.destroy' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@destroy']);
Route::any('equipment/loadManufacturer', ['as'=>'equipment.loadManufacturer','uses'=>'EquipmentController@loadManufacturer']);
Route::any('equipment/loadMachine', ['as'=>'equipment.loadMachine','uses'=>'EquipmentController@loadMachine']);
Route::any('equipment/loadModel', ['as'=>'equipment.loadModel','uses'=>'EquipmentController@loadModel']);
Route::any('equipment/loadImage', ['as'=>'equipment.loadImage','uses'=>'EquipmentController@loadImage']);});
```

The login page and equipment page works but the SOS and Order routes do not.

I'm using php artisan serve

Here's part of the Order Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\So;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Equipment;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Leasing;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Session;
use DB;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Mail;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
     //create a variable and store all the blog posts in it from the dataabse
    $orders = Order::all();

    //return a view and pass in the above varaible
    return view('order.index')->with('orders', $orders);  

}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
```

here's the route list

[image]

php artisan dump-autoload

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "dump-autoload" is not defined.

```
 composer dump-autoload
 Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is     recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
 Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Post the full error stack.

Comment: Are you using artisan serve or something else?

Comment: i added the full error stack and i'm using artisan serve

Comment: have you tried composer dump-autoload? Also could you show us result of php artisan routes:list ?

Comment: the dump didnt work.

Comment: can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In command line fire below command then try to access url

```
php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=8000
```

Comment: The original computer was using XAMP and the new computer is running WAMP, does this make a difference?

Comment: If you want to go with "WAMP" then just go to the project folder and run the above command it's working fine in "WAMP" as well as "XAMP" too.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from WAMP to XAMP and it worked.